# Why doesn't the instanceof operator use camelcase notation?

Tags: java, camelcasing

```
Foo bar = new Foo();
if(bar instanceof Foo){
    ... // it's true
}
```

I was just wondering why we don't use camelcase notation (`instanceOf`) instead of how it is (`instanceof`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`instanceof` is an operator and a reserved word, not a method or variable. Camel case is used in Java for method names and variable names.

Answer (score 1):

because `instanceof` is an operator, `Camel casing` is meant for methods and variables

Answer (score 1):

method name is defined as lowerCamelCase
https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.2.3-method-names

and operators are predefined symbols